# JMeter: Is there command or API to check the connection of slave machines in JMeter?

Tags: java, jmeter

I've been working on with distributed tests with JMeter and wonder if there's a command to check worker nodes(slave machines) are ready to start test. I know -R flag helps to run distributed test with CLI but I want to know if there's a command line to check connection. For example, below the image, does JMeter provide command checks each server (192.168.0.10, 192.168.0.15) ready to start the test.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't come across a feature that can validate the state of slaves. And even I had this same question when I started with distributed load testing.
I ended up creating a simple jmx file with 1 thread group and 1 http sampler and hitting either google.com or any other GET api. I check the response in `View Results Tree` and if I see request executed by each slave, then I know everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

As of current version [JMeter 5.4.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-4-1-released-td5739226.html) there is no possibility to validate the connectivity of remote slave engines without running the test itself.

So you can create a simple test with one [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler hitting http://example.com website or something like a [Dummy Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-dummy-sampler-the-ultimate-guide) and run it with 1 user / 1 iteration